# Inheritance vs Composition vs Combination

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, composition

I'm currently working on a library. One of my classes (Class A) needs the functionality Class B provides. Suppose Class A calls upon the members of Class A frequently (almost in every member of it). In order to use Class B in Class A what is the best approach:

1. Inheritance: Class A would inherit class B, gaining access to its functionality.
2. Composition: Have a member of type "Class B" in class A, thus being able to use its functionality.
3. Combination: Combining both classes and creating a new class containing all the members A and B had. (Class A is unlikely to be used by other developers)

Which method has the advantages in speed efficiency (function calls, etc.), maintenance, and memory efficiency?

Comment: pretty sure that highly depends on what exactly is the functionality you want. Ask yourself a question: **Is B a form of A, or just I want B do to similar things as A does?** If the answer to the first part is *yes* - use inheritance. If the answer to the second part is *yes* - use composition. I don't really see the benefit of combining them both unless that's gonna make further implementation a lot more clear

Comment: composition unless A really is a kind of B.

Comment: btw I would skip 2 out of the 3 advantages you are asking for. Write code for clarity (ie maintenance) first and only then care about efficiency. Readable code either is already efficient or much easier to modify into something more efficient than code that is unnecessarily obfuscated with efficiency hacks